# Scrapy logging call stack each time message is output

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I am running Scrapy via a python script in the terminal. On my local machine, Scrapy messages are not accompanied by any error messages. However, on production terminal, each message is accompanied by an entire call stack. Any idea what is causing this?

I am trying to set up Scrapy to only output important info, such as the last line in the log,

```
"Message: 'Crawled (%(status)s) %(request)s%(request_flags)s (referer: %(referer)s)%(response_flags)s'
Arguments: {'status': 200, 'request': <GET https://www.kmart.com/Sitemap_product_MP_1192.xml.gz>, 'request_flags': '', 'referer': 'https://www.kmart.com/Sitemap_Index_Product_MP_1.xml', 'response_flags': '', 'flags': ''}"
```

I have tried adjusting the Scrapy logging settings here, http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html. Not even setting it to CRITICAL fixes this issue. Please help.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 33, in emit
    payload = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 833, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 542, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 386, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'request_id'
Call stack:
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    SpiderTasks.run_spider_for_alexa_site_id(alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/code/green_brick_two/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/scripts/spider_scripts/spider_tasks.py", line 19, in run_spider_for_alexa_site_id
    process.start()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 293, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1261, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1273, in mainLoop
    self.doIteration(t)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 235, in doPoll
    log.callWithLogger(selectable, _drdw, selectable, fd, event)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/log.py", line 103, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 614, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 205, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 211, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 330, in dataReceived
    self._flushReceiveBIO()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 295, in _flushReceiveBIO
    ProtocolWrapper.dataReceived(self, bytes)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/protocols/policies.py", line 120, in dataReceived
    self.wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 125, in dataReceived
    return self._wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 1616, in dataReceived
    self._parser.dataReceived(bytes)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 389, in dataReceived
    HTTPParser.dataReceived(self, data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 579, in dataReceived
    why = self.rawDataReceived(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 302, in rawDataReceived
    self.bodyDecoder.dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/http.py", line 1654, in dataReceived
    finishCallback(data[contentLength:])
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 454, in _finished
    self.finisher(rest)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 973, in dispatcher
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 1570, in _finishResponse_WAITING
    self._disconnectParser(reason)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 1596, in _disconnectParser
    parser.connectionLost(reason)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 565, in connectionLost
    self.response._bodyDataFinished()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 973, in dispatcher
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 1229, in _bodyDataFinished_CONNECTED
    self._bodyProtocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 469, in connectionLost
    self._finished.callback((self._txresponse, body, None))
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 459, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 567, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 459, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 567, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1442, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1429, in _inlineCallbacks
    deferred.callback(e.value)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 459, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 567, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 238, in _on_success
    logger.log(*logformatter_adapter(logkws), extra={'spider': spider})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1367, in log
    self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/logging.py", line 47, in sentry_patched_callhandlers
    return old_callhandlers(self, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 38, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: 'Crawled (%(status)s) %(request)s%(request_flags)s (referer: %(referer)s)%(response_flags)s'
Arguments: {'status': 200, 'request': <GET https://www.kmart.com/Sitemap_product_MP_1192.xml.gz>, 'request_flags': '', 'referer': 'https://www.kmart.com/Sitemap_Index_Product_MP_1.xml', 'response_flags': '', 'flags': ''}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your code:

> KeyError: 'request_id'

Seems like you define `request_id` in some formatting pattern and the pattern never receives any keys like that.

Fixing this will get rid of the traceback.